# Bezier Curve does not follow parented armature

Tags: armature, bezier-curves, hook-modifier

My Bezier Curve-handles uses hooks that are parented to bones in the armature. The handles are customized to stick out from the mesh. When rotating or moving the bones, the curve does not follow as expected and seems stuck in the middle. How can I automatically have the curve follow the bone more naturally?

[image]

[image]

Original simplified post: [Bezier Curve cable handles not following armature bone rotation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/308412/bezier-curve-cable-handles-not-following-armature-bone-rotation)

Comment: I think you should provide an example file. For instance, we don't know here how the curve is made ? Two points, more ?

Comment: Yes, two points. The file was now added to the post

Comment: ok, but in between, you've answered your question, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The Bezier Curve itself was not parented to the armature. After parenting it to the correct bone, everything worked.